# Mobile version of website is zoomed in on launch

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

When my website (www.missnisaa.com) is launched on mobile the page is zoomed in. The user needs to pinch in order to get the right scale. How do I get the right scale on launch?

I have tried changing the initial scale, maximum scale and minimum scale to various numbers to no avail

This is the current code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
```

I have also tried changing the css. Current code:

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*Mobile*/
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen
  and (max-width: 768px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
html {
 -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important;
}
```

The page is always zoomed in regardless of mobile browser. I have only tested on iOS as I dont have an android phone to test on.

Answer (score 0):

You have `width: 768px !important;` in the CSS rule for `body` (in a media query below 768px). So your content will always be too wide for smartphones, which is why your iPhone obviously zooms the too-wide body to fit it into the screen. Just remove that - the default `auto` width is 100% which is what you need for a responsive website.

Answer (score 0):

I removed that line and nothing has changed with the exception on safari and the banner image and text are now squashed to the left.

I also tried

```
width: 100% !important;
```

but that doesn't work either.